# Module-Swift.h has compile error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a swift class that I use in Objective-C, so the Module-Swift.h is auto-generated. However, the auto-generated .h file has compile error...The code looks like this:

```
class SwiftClass: ObjectiveCClass {
let enteringStr : String = "Entering"
let exitingStr :String = "Exiting"
let dwellInsideStr : String = "Dwell Inside"
let dwellOutsideStr :String = "Dwell Outside"

var userId : String?
var triggerType : String?
```

}

In the generated Module-Swift.h file, it looks like this:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("SwiftClass")
@interface SwiftClass : ObjectiveCClass
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * enteringStr;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * exitingStr;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * dwellInsideStr;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * dwellOutsideStr;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * userId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * triggerType;
```

However, there are a lot of compile errors for the first 4 variables. They are:

- Expected ';' at the end of declaration list
- Expected an Objective-C directive after '@'
- Expected member name of ';' after declaration specifier
- Property requires fields to be named

Same errors for all 4 of them. ObjectiveCClass is a third party API class that extends NSOBject. What's even more weird is that this error didn't happen when I just changed few objective-c classes into swift in my project, and this class has already been migrated without problem earlier. But, this appeared after I migrated more into swift.

Comment: Please add `ObjectiveCClass` code and everything else to make the problem reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have properties with the same name somewhere else in your objective-c code